# How to remove canonical tag from product page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, tags, canonical, remove

I want to remove default canonical link only from product page. I have set the values to "No" in backend configuration. see https://prnt.sc/JAUrcfGsDUai
Still the canonical link is visible on view page source. https://prnt.sc/JAUrcfGsDUai

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Make sure remove based on your scope.

Comment: Yes it is removed from scope

Comment: hope you clear the cache and then check.

Comment: yes , thats the basic thing which everyone does for sure.